# xmlrpc response datatype long possible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib, simplexmlrpcserver

Is there any possibility to allow xmlrpc extensions (datatype `long int`) for the Python simplexmlrpc server?

The client uses Apache xmlrpc, which [allows 8 byte integers](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/types.html).

Basically, I'm using the [example code](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html) with this function to test it:

```
def FcnRLong():
    x=8000000000L
    return x
```

which results in this error:

```
Java exception occurred:
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: <type 'exceptions.OverflowError'>:long int exceeds XML-RPC limits
```

Any ideas? Is there any xmlrpc server for Python 2.7 which supports `long int`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second line in the following snippet changes the marshalling for long integers to emit `<i8>` instead of `<int>`. Yes, it's not too pretty, but should work and fix the problem.

```
>>> import xmlrpclib
>>> xmlrpclib.Marshaller.dispatch[type(0L)] = lambda _, v, w: w("<value><i8>%d</i8></value>" % v)
>>> xmlrpclib.dumps((2**63-1,))
'<params>\n<param>\n<value><i8>9223372036854775807</i8></value></param>\n</params>\n'
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! You'll get the bounty in 4 hours ;)

Comment: Perfect simple solution. Some clients require `"<value><i8>%d</i8></value>"`, some `"<value><ex:i8>%d</ex:i8></value>"`, most accept both.

Comment: Isn't it cleaner to simply use `long` instead of `type(0L)` ?

Comment: In my case, sending the number as a string instead of trying to send it as an integer(convert to string and remove suffix 'L') worked, but I guess it depends on the implementation. Just think it's worth trying as it's a clearer solution.

Comment: This works when I use `xmlrpclib.dumps()` as in the given example, but I still get the error when using `xmlrpclib.ServerProxy`.